# Can one obtaining a mean value form of the Taylor series remainder using the integral remainder?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Can we show that $$(\exists \epsilon \in[0,x])\left(\int_{0}^x \frac{(x-s)^n f^{(n+1)}(s)}{n!}ds= \frac{x^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}( \epsilon)}{k!}\right)\text{ ?}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the mean value theorem for integrals. If $g \geqslant 0$ and $f$ is continuous, there is a $c\in (a,b)$ with $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx = f(c)\int_a^b g(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer For a proof, would this be sufficent? : Let

$$f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$$ and $$m= \inf f$$ $$M= \sup f$$ Then $$M\int_{a}^b g(x)dx \ge \int_{a}^b f(x)g(x)dx \ge m\int_{a}^b g(x)dx$$. So since $f$ is continous, such $c$ exists due to the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Yes. That is the proof I remember, I'd say the standard proof.